# Is TSA Pre-Check's KTN more reliable than Global Entry's?

Tags: global-entry, tsa-precheck

A few months ago I got TSA Pre-Check because I had a last minute domestic flight and was able to schedule the interview quickly.  As I will be flying out of the country in a few months, I just got approved for Global Entry, so I now have two KTNs.  I know I can use either.

From what I've read, though, it seems that Global Entry is spotty with whether or not you actually get Pre-Check.  I've read some people getting it about 50% of the time.  Aside from random selection for full screening, will it be more reliable to use my Pre-Check KTN rather than my new GE number?

Thanks!

Comment: Huh. I have global entry and have never not gotten pre-check in the past two years and about twenty flights, international and domestic.

Comment: I have GE and have always gotten pre-check.

Comment: @RoboKaren Were you flying on airlines that participate in Pre-Check? See [TSA Pre✓® Participating Airlines](https://www.tsa.gov/precheck/participating-airlines).

Comment: I think people are forgetting that in English a double negative is a positive -- i.e., I've always gotten PreCheck via global entry.

Comment: @RoboKaren but reading quickly, perhaps people overlooked the"not" as I just did.

Answer (score 4):

All four programs, TSA PreCheck, Global Entry, Nexus and Sentri give you a Known Traveler Number to register with the airlines.  Basically, it's essentially the same thing no matter how you get it.

*IF* there is a difference (huge if), they'll never say but I have been using my GE KTN for years now with no issues.

For you, it's very easy to test. If you check in early and don't get Pre with one KTN, just go to the counter, change the KTN and have them re-issue the Boarding Pass.  This worked for me after mis-entering the KTN when I flew an airline for the first time.