# Does TSA Precheck work when US citizens are exiting the US on a registered foreign passport?

Tags: usa, us-citizens, dual-nationality, global-entry, tsa-precheck

I have Global Entry via my United States citizenship. During the application, they asked me to declare all foreign citizenships I have and to take those passports with me to the interview (where they were inspected).

I am flying directly from the US to one of my other countries of citizenship (not an eligible country for Global Entry), and will need to check into the airline using my non-US passport (as the country is not visa-free for US nationals). However, this passport was registered as belonging to me during the Global Entry interview.

Does anyone know if the purpose of making me present my other passports was solely for security purposes, or if that also makes them registered and usable for Pre-Check?

Comment: when I check in, in addition to passport numbers, I have a chance to enter a Known Traveler Number (KTN) which is on my Nexus card. I presume you have one on your GE card. This will qualify you for precheck independently of your passports, your airline status, etc. See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/94656/is-tsa-pre-checks-ktn-more-reliable-than-global-entrys#

Answer (score 8, accepted):

During booking or check in you can add your Known Traveller Number (i.e. Global Entry, Nexus, etc.) to the booking and in most cases this will give you Pre Check. That's independent on what passport you are using to travel.

Even easier: make an account with the airline directly and add the Known Traveller Number to your profile and add you booking to your account as well.

Sometimes I present two  passports at Check In, especially if I leave the departure country on a different passport than I'm using to enter the destination country. That's typically not necessary in the US. Technically you are required to exit the US with your US passport but there are no exit controls, so it's a moot point.

Comment: +1 for the airline account. I don't have to enter my KTN when I book via a third-party site with my primary airline because they match up my FF profile automatically.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter which passport you use for travelling (but remember that you must arrive in the US with your US passport), TSA Pre is not related to that.

You need to add your Known Traveller Number (written on the back of the Global Entry card) into your booking (at least 24h *before* you check-in create your boarding pass). This is easiest on the airline's website - just look up your trip by its code, and add the number.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that TSA Pre✔️ is available if the airline participates in the  TSA Pre✔️ program.

TSA lists participating airlines on [this page](https://www.tsa.gov/precheck/participating-airlines).